# zsh completion: stop completing when wrong option is used

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

My script `foo` takes directories in given path `/foo/path` as argument, plus it has one optional argument `-l`.

I have this completion file:

```
#compdef foo

 _arguments : \
    '-l' \
    '*: :->directory'

 case $state in
    directory)
        _directories -W /foo/path
 ;;
 esac
```

I am having followng issues with the completion:

When I use a wrong (non-existent) optional argument, for example `-c`, and then press tab

```
foo -c <TAB>
```

then it automatically completes the existent option `-l`, as if the directory completion has been eliminated bu the non-existent option `-c`.

This is strange, because I would have at least expected it will again offer both the directories, and `-l`.

But anyway, if wrong/non-existent option is provided, how can I stop the completions completely, to make clear that it cannot continue with wrong options?

Comment: With this code, I can't reproduce the behavior you decribe. After `foo -c `, if I press TAB, the completions offered are the directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code, I can't reproduce the behavior you decribe. After `foo -c` , if I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the completions offered are the directories.

Note that when you use states with `_arguments`, you should declare the variables it uses as local variables in the function. I don't think it matters in this simple case if there are no global variables with the same name.

---

I don't think there's a way to specify a behavior for all arguments beginning with `-`. To disable completions if there's an unrecognized option, I can't think of a better way than iterating over the arguments, i.e. the elements of [`words`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-words) between 1 (command name, exclusive) and `$CURRENT` (word being completed, exclusive).

```
local context state state_descr line
typeset -A opt_args

 _arguments : \
  '-l' \
  '*: :->directory'

 local i
 for ((i = 2; i < CURRENT; i++)); do
   if [[ $words[$i] = -* && $words[$i] != -l ]]; then
     state=nothing
     break
   fi
 done

 case $state in
   directory)
     _directories -W /usr
   ;;
 esac
```

Comment: why are you declaring `local context state state_descr line`, when only `state` appears in the code? The other variables are not used at all.

Comment: and same with `opt_args`.

Comment: @400theCat They're used inside `_arguments`. See the documentation of `_arguments`.